# ScrollView not scrolling when dragging on buttons

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibutton, ios-simulator

I have a scroll view that used to scroll when it didn't have buttons all over it. Now it does, and when dragging the mouse (on simulator) nothing happens (i think because the buttons are being pushed). How can I make this right?

Comment: Have you tried it on a physical device, there are several differences between devices and the simulator, and the mouse and multi-touch is one of the biggest!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This is happening because `UIButton` subviews of the `UIScrollView` (I assume buttons are added as subviews in your case) are tracking the touches and not the scroll view. `UIScrollView` method `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` is the key here. According to its description: "The default returned value is YES if view is not a `UIControl` object; otherwise, it returns `NO`.", i.e. for `UIControl` objects (buttons), `UIScrollView` does not attempt to cancel touches which prevents scrolling.

So, to allow scrolling with buttons:

1. Make sure `UIScrollView` property `canCancelContentTouches` is set to `YES`.
2. Subclass `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` to return `YES` when content view object is a `UIButton`, like this:

```objc
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    if ( [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] ) {
        return YES;
    }

    return [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I changed the scroll having images to simulate buttons (and tracking touches to know when to call a method) I will try your solution though and see how it works. thanks!

Comment: @DanielaM If this marvelous answer has helped you as it really seems, it would be good to accept it.

Comment: **bold** @Roman K - You are my HERO!

I've spent 2 days reading in many posts\forums about this overlapping problem but no tweak or solution really worked. Your solution really works!! 

Cheers :-)

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. touchesShouldCancelInContentView is never called, unless I set the delay to NO, but in the latter case, there is no scroll at all.

Comment: I really appreciate this insight.

Comment: Appreciate this one as well

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue for me. Note that I had UIPanGestureRecognizer recognizer on the subview and I needed to delete it in order to make this work.

Comment: Can you provide an example for touchesShouldCancelInContentView ?

Comment: I added an example. Note that I would actually check for `UIControl` instead of `UIButton`, in case a slider or stepper or switch showed up at some point.

Comment: The issue persists again in iOS 8 and `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` is not working anymore. But, the scrolling stuck only sometimes. Not always.

Comment: @MinSoe What did you do for that?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25900859/206592) helps me solve the problem. I think iOS 8 is having a lot of issue despite of having not a lot of changes in UI because of SWIFT

Comment: @Roman Kishchenko what if the buttons aren't added as subviews of the scrollview?

Answer (score 18):

I founded this question looking for the swift solution for this problem, I "translated" it like this:

**Swift 5**

```
class UIButtonScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        if view.isKind(of: UIButton.self) {
          return true
        }

        return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
    }    
}
```

hope this could help

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3 Solution**

```
override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if view is UIButton {
        return true
    }
    return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try if you're seeing this in a simulator is to run on an actual phone. I couldn't scroll in the simulator but no prob on my phone.

Comment: You're right. But that's so weird. Do you know what that happens?

Comment: @flopshot Sorry, no clue apart from an emulator bug. Not sure it's fixable by the average user.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it with this way.

**in ViewDidLoad**

```
self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches;
```

**in .m**

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```