# UIButton Doesn't allow UIScrollView to scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have many `UIButtons` within a `UIScrollView`.  Those `UIButtons` have actions attached to them in `Touch Down Repeat`.  My problem is my scroll view doesn't scroll when I touch a button then scroll, but it works fine if I touch outside of the button.

How can I allow my scroll view to scroll even though a button is pressed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as you have the `Cancellable Content Touches` in Interface Builder set it should work.  You can also set it in code:

```
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```

Comment: Wow, a simple checkbox fixes my issue.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Also check out the `Delay Content Touches` property and docs, may be relevant to what you're doing as well.

Comment: Note that you also need to subclass UIScrollView to really make it work. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3550157/908621 for details

Comment: Above comment with link is vital to correctly handle this situation.

Comment: What if ScrollView is added on the cell of UITableView? Will it work in thatb case? I don't think so

Answer (score 9):

So `view.canCancelContentTouches = YES` works OK if you don't also have `delaysContentTouches` set to `YES`. If you do though, the buttons won't work at all. What you need to do is subclass the `UIScrollView` (or `UICollectionView`/`UITableView`) and implement the following:

**Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:UIButton.class]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if view is UIButton {
        return true
    }
    return super.touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with `delaysTouchesBegan` as a property set to `true`.