# Cant move UIScrollView that has buttons in it when pressing and dragging the buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that has buttons inside it and when I'm trying to press a button and sliding to the side the `UIScrollView` doesn't move but when I'm sliding really fast it does move. I'm using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` on the button. This is the code that I'm using to add buttons to the scroll view:

```
-(void) setScrollView:(int) numberOfViews {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * 40;
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(scrollViewButtonClicked:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 40, 40);
        button.tag = 1000+i;
        button.backgroundColor = [self getColorForSound:self.sounds[i]];
        [button setExclusiveTouch:YES];
        [self.soundsScrollView addSubview:button];
}
}
```

How can I make the `UIScrollView` scroll even if the user pressed the button and tries to scroll?

Comment: Have you tried using Touch Drag inside for the button? touch up can fire the current actions, and touch drag can do what you want to do.

Comment: @calvinBhai this doesn't work. I need to scroll it to the side and this doesn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIButton Doesn't allow UIScrollView to scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070135/uibutton-doesnt-allow-uiscrollview-to-scroll)

Comment: @Amar the answer there to set Cancellable Content Touches to yes doesn't work for me.

Comment: @BlueGene Also, check the link given in the comments of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Conceptually, only one view should be processing a touch event. When you touch a button, only the button related processing is handled (e.g., button press). the touch event cannot be processed by both the button and the scroll view at the same time. Once you start a touch event in a button, the button "owns" that touch and so the scroll view doesn't get to process it.

The reason why when you slide "really fast" the scroll view does move is because your scroll view gets to inspect a touch event first since it is the parent view of your buttons. If the touch event isn't "moving", it will pass it along to subviews, in this case your buttons, to see if they can process it. However, if the scroll view detects that touch is moving before the button has a chance to process the touch event, then the scroll view will take ownership of the touch event and process it for scrolling.

Comment: the question is whatever when I run the app on the iPhone and slide my finger it will work correctly and the reason it doesn't work in the simulator is because i use a mouse and press or will it keep this way in the iPhone?