# Table with static cells won't scroll when I set delaysContentTouches = false

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uibutton, highlight

### The problem: HIGHLIGHT vs SCROLLING

My buttons inside the cell where not getting highlighted when I lightly tap on them. I had to tap hard and for a long time to be able to see the tap state of the button.

So I did this in order to set the delaysContentTouches to false (I didn't manage other way to do it) inside viewDidLoad():

```
   for index in tableView.subviews {
        if (index.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView)) {
            let scrollViewFound = index as! UIScrollView
            scrollViewFound.delegate = self
            scrollViewFound.delaysContentTouches = false
            scrollViewFound.canCancelContentTouches = true
            scrollViewFound.scrollEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

This way the buttons highlight correctly but then **I cannot scroll the table up or down**, unless I start dragging from one of the empty cells --> `userInteractionEnable = false` in the empty cells

---

### What I need:

**To be able to highlight the buttons but also to scroll the table**.
Is it even possible to have both, scrollable view and highlighted buttons?

---

### What I have tried

I tried calling this function:

```
func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    print("touchesShouldCancelInContentView happening---------")
    return true
}
```

Which never gets called. I tried overriding But it gives an error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Which is weird, because UITableViewController inherits from UIScrollView. I also tried adding UIScrollViewDelegate to the class definition, but of course it gives another error that this is redundant.

---

### Extra Information

**The class** is declared like this:

```
class Settings: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ...
```

**The tableView** is made of Static Cells

**The cells**:

- *Some are empty:* where UserInteractionEnable = false
- *Some have buttons with text field:* I want these buttons to get highlighted. UserInteractionEnable = true. The button action is called by **.TouchUpInside**
- *Some have labels and a check image:* Their action gets called in didSelectRowAtIndexPath which will change the labels colour and check images

> Maybe it is relevant to say that when user clicks on any cell `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it will
>   call a function to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: How are you setting the `UIControlAction` for the button? It should be `.TouchUpInside`. If you have it at `.TouchesBegan` or something else you won't be able to scroll. With `.TouchUpInside` your button will only be selected if the user taps within button bounds and taps back up while still in its bounds. But Scrolling a tableView would be a drag Gesture and therfore shouldn't select the button.

Comment: Hello @NSGangster It is called by `.TouchUpInside` I just edited the question, maybe it is relevant to say that I have a dismissKeyboard function that gets called whenever the user clicks at any cell.

Comment: Im @ work atm. I'll take a closer look at this on my break.

Comment: Thank you @NSGangster this is really bringing me crazy. I also think I am not subclassing the UIScrollView function right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to subclass the wrong class, that's why it doesn't work. You have to subclass the `UITableView` class itself, and not the `UITableViewController`.
Can you try the following ?

#### - First

Subclass the TableView class in order to override the `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` function.

```
class UIDraggableTableView: UITableView {

    override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {
        if (view.isKindOfClass(UIButton)) {
            return true
        }
        return super.touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view)
    }
}
```

#### - Second

In your `TableViewController` class, when `viewDidLoad()` is called, append the following right after `super.viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.tableView = DraggableTableView()
```

This should solve your issue.

Part of this answer was taken from [this **StackOverflow** post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512563/scrollview-not-scrolling-when-dragging-on-buttons).