# UIButtons blocks UIScrollView scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that has a custom `UIView` subclass. On this `UIView` there are several `UIButton`s spreads on the view, the hierarchy of the `UIViewController` is:

> UIViewConteroller's View > Custom UIView > UIScrollView > Custom
>   UIView > UIButtons.

The problem is that when I try to scroll the scrollView, it doesn't scroll if I start the scrolling from one of the buttons. It does scroll if I start it from one of the gaps between each button.

How can I make the scrollView scroll even when I start the scroll from the button (and the button will be triggered just if I click it)?

I've tried to set `canCancelContentTouches` to `true` but it didn't work.
I've tried to subclass `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldCancel` but it still doesn't work when I start a scroll from one of the buttons...

Thank you!

Comment: could you post your hierarchy of viewController

Comment: @VinodKumar `UIViewConteroller's View` > `Custom UIView` > `UIScrollView` > `Custom UIView` > `UIButtons`

Comment: you might want to check [this Q&As](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512563/scrollview-not-scrolling-when-dragging-on-buttons).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ScrollView not scrolling when dragging on buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512563/scrollview-not-scrolling-when-dragging-on-buttons)

Comment: @AhmadF I've already tried it. It still doesn't work when I start a scroll from one of the buttons...

Comment: @ron27 It's not a duplicate, the solution they've suggested doesn't work

Comment: @FS.O6 Okay. Thanks for the reply.