# iOS / Swift : How can I scroll a view up or down when touch event starts on a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

Using UIKit:

I've got a view that has multiple `UIButton`, but I can only scroll the view up or down if I began my scroll touch event outside the `UIButton`.

So how can I make it so that I can scroll my view, regardless if I start my touch event on a `UIButton`?

Comment: What do you mean "...I can only swipe the view up or down if I start my view on a non-UIButton"? If you start the swipe action on a non-button?

Comment: try `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true`

Answer (score 0):

If your view behaves like a scroll view, try solution as below
It has been proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26292829/9191054 and it works!

```
 class UIButtonScrollView: UIScrollView {
    
        override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
            if view.isKind(of: UIButton.self) {
              return true
            }
    
            return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
        }    
    }
```